# Setting value for data when field is blank

Tags: php, xml, parsing, xml-parsing, simplexml

I am parsing an XML file using simpleXML to get the dates from the below data attributes:

```
<start_time>2012-01-22 09:00:00</start_time>
<stop_time>2012-03-18 15:00:00</stop_time>
```

using this:

```
echo 'Start Date:'.substr("$events->start_time", 0, 10).'<br />';
echo 'End Date:'.substr("$events->stop_time", 0, 10).'<br />';
```

My issue is that on some entries, there are no `stop_time` values given and when parsing the xml it pulls `0000-00-00` in the event there is nothing there.  In plain terms this means the `start_time` and `stop_time` are the same day when this occurs in the xml file.

My Question:
**How do I set `start_time` as the `stop_time` value for entries with no value given for `stop_time`?**

Comment: Move your `substr()` functions to set variables and then use an `if` to determine if the start value needs to be doubled before `echo`ing the variables?

Comment: The `if` was the way to go. Thanks man. Just needed to think it through a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Went with this as the parse wasn't setting a value for stop_time:

```
//End Date
if ($enddate = substr("$events->stop_time", 0, 10)) {
    echo '<strong>End Date:</strong>'.substr("$events->stop_time", 0, 10).'<br />';
} else {
    echo '<strong>End Date:</strong>'.substr("$events->start_time", 0, 10).'<br />';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe:

```
echo 'End Date:'.(isset($events->stop_time) ? substr($events->stop_time, 0, 10) : substr($events->start_time, 0, 10)).'<br />';
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a simple ternary to replace the output with the start time if the stop time is 0000-00-00:

```
echo 'Start Date:'.substr("$events->start_time", 0, 10).'<br />';
echo 'End Date:'.$events->stop_time == "000-00-00" ? substr("$events->start_time", 0, 10) : substr("$events->stop_time", 0, 10).'<br />';
```

Comment: Another ternary. Another ick.

Comment: Personally I think the ternary syntax is great - concise & clear (assuming you don't use nested ternary statements).

Comment: It's compelling if rarely used, in my opinion. They work but they're easy to screw up and visually not easy to debug. On that note, you're missing a `"` or have an extra `"` on that line.

Comment: Your solution looks to assume the value of 000-00-00 is there already.  The XML has no value, its blank for stop_time so the parse is returning 000-00-00 just to fill something it appears.

Comment: If your parser doesn't set a value for the stop time then you can use the solution given by k102 (i.e. check isset($events->stop_time))